# What happens if Mosquitto runs out of memory to store QoS 1/2 messages?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

In MQTT, messages with QoS 1 or 2 [*must* be delivered at least once](http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-6-mqtt-quality-of-service-levels) (QoS 2 messages must be delivered *exactly* once). If the client is not connected, the broker must store the message until the client is ready to receive it.

The [HiveMQ blog](http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-7-persistent-session-queuing-messages) has an interesting point:

> **But what happens if a client does not come online for a long time?** The constraint for storing messages is often the memory limit of the operating system. There is no standard way on what to do in this scenario. It totally depends on the use case. In HiveMQ we will provide a possibility to manipulate queued message and purge them.

Since this seems to be dependent on the broker, **how does Mosquitto handle this situation?** Does it just crash after running out of memory or are old messages finally purged?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Messages are persisted to disk not just held in memory.

Look at the `autosave_interval` and `autosave_on_change` options for when the messages get written to disk.

<sub>[Source](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html)</sub>

Comment: Is my understanding correct that the messages are written to disk however the in-memory is not flushed, causing the mosquitto broker to be limited by the memory of the OS rather than the disk storage. It crashes once the memory exceeds.

Comment: @BhavinJethra https://iot.stackexchange.com/a/3021/746